# How to set up Notifications using Aiogram

Tags: python, async-await, notifications, python-asyncio, aiogram

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to implement function to my Telegram bot, which should check data from database, compare time and send notification if time has come.
However I have this type of mistake:

> DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop loop =
> asyncio.get_event_loop()

Here is a function code:

```
async def run_notify():
    while True:
        base = sq.connect("actions.db")
        cur = base.cursor()
        all_data = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM actions").fetchall()
        delta = timedelta(days=1)
        for each_train in all_data:
            each_train = str(each_train)
            each_train = re.sub("[(|)|'|,]", "", each_train)
            data_info = datetime.strptime(each_train, "%d %m %Y %H:%M")
            today = datetime.now()
            if today == (data_info - delta):
                await bot.send_message(chat_id=-530468333, text= f"Reminder {data_info}")  
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

And the main part:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(run_notify())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

How can I fix this Error and are there any other possible ways to implement Notifications?
Thanks